# Python. Make nested dictionary from directories hierarchy

Tags: python, directory, python-os

I need to make a nested dictionary which presents directory structure using `os` with following rules:

1) if folder contains more than one element, the value is list of dictionaries or filenames;

2) if folder contains only file, the value is just it's name

3) if folder contains nested folders, the value is dictionary

I guess it's much clear on the example picture, where you can see the directory structure and the structure of dictionary which is needed as a result:

[image: Example]

I checked the questions which are close to mine but can't get how I should do my task. This is the code I wrote but it's far away from the solution. I'm stucked because don't know how to organize recursively-walk through the folders in a right way:

```
def my_folder_analysis(dir_name):
    dir = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name):
        for subdir in dirs:
            if len(os.listdir(os.path.join(root, subdir))) > 1:
                subdir_dict = {subdir : []}
                for x in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, subdir)):
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, subdir, x)):
                        #add file to list of folder elements
                        subdir_dict[subdir].append(x)
```

How should I do it?

Comment: You are not assigned subdir_dict to the dir dictionary and the subdir_dict  is overwritten on each  subdir  without to be stored

Comment: Actually I don't know how to finish subdir_dict organization for current subdir with a given rules, so I didn't add it to dir as subdir_dict is still not right